# for in 文の使い方

Tags: swift, realm

`swift`で`for-in`文を使おうとしているのですが、うまくいきません。
下のコードの`wordData.append`の行で、「`RLMObject does not have a member named word`」というエラーが表示されてしまいます。
`Word`というクラスには`word`というメンバ変数が存在しています。
なので初歩的なことでしょうけど、どうすればいいかわからなくなり詰まってしまいました。
どなたか分かる方がいればどこが間違っているのかを教えていただきたいです。
すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
    var wordData: [String] = []
    let word = Word.objectsWhere("speech == A")

    for wordStore in word {
        wordData.append(wordStore.word)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ダウンキャストが必要です。

```
for item in word {
    if let wordStore = item as? Word {
        wordData.append(wordStore.word)
    }
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご提示の方法で正常に動かすことができました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

※ Realmを使っていると知らず以下の様な回答をしました・・・ダウンキャストが対応として正しいと思います。

Word#objectsWhereはどのように宣言されていますか？

```
class Word {
   class func objectsWhere(where: String) -> [Word] {
      // Do something.
   }
}
```

のようになっていれば以下のコードはコンパイル可能だと思います（変数名をわかりやすく変更しましたが、やっていることは同じです）

```
var wordData: [String] = []
let wordArray = Word.objectsWhere("speech == A")

for word in wordArray {
    wordData.append(word.word)
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Wordクラスにはclass func objectWhereの記述はしていません。objectWhereを使うにはWordクラスで宣言しておかなければ使えないのでしょうか？そして宣言しておかなければならないとすれば、ご提示いただいたコードの //Do something には何を書けばよろしいでしょうか？ http://qiita.com/okitsutakatomo/items/9134c5fa8bd4384a2acf このサイトの中段あたりにobjectWhereの使い方が載っており、モデルクラスで宣言しなくても使えるものと思っていたのですが。。。分からないことが多くて質問ばかりで申し訳ないのですが、上記の疑問を教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Realmというライブラリを使っているのですね。すみません、Realmは使ったことがないもので・・・ドキュメントを見ましたが、Word#objectsWhereの実体はRLMObject#objectsWhereで、戻り値はRLMResultsのようですね。これをfor inにかけるとRLMObjectを取り出すことになります。RLMObjectはWordの親クラスですからwordというプロパティはありません。おっしゃるようなエラーになります。

ですのでダウンキャストで対応するのが正攻法のように思います。

Comment: 上記のダウンキャストの方法でよろしかったのですね。了解しました。
ただ、for文の後で試しに println("wordStore: \(wordData[0])") としてみると、「fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value」というエラーが出てしまいました。これはどうすれば値を取り出すことができるでしょうか？キャストによる問題でしょうか？